# Python on Azure Function error is "OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "Mypassword@database_ip" to address"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, azure-functions

I have a python function that connects to Azure Postgresql and selects query some rows. In local run without problem. When I published on Azure and run it I received the below error:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "Mypassword@database_ip" to address
```

[image]

I don't know why to change connection format to `db_password@db_ip`, as you see on screenshot.

My function is:

```
def get_engine(database='db_name', username='username', password='@password', host='ip', port=5432):
    engine_string = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}"
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_string)
    print("Database connection done!")
    return engine
```

Comment: On line after `engine_string = ...`  do `print(engine_string)` to see what you are actually building. Post result as update to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using plain string formatting you can use [engine.URL.create](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html?highlight=url#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create) to protect yourself against "special characters" in the username, password, etc.:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
    username="username",
    password="@password",
    host="ip",
    port=5432,
    database="database",
)
print(url)  # postgresql+psycopg2://username:%40password@ip:5432/database
engine = sa.create_engine(url)
``
```

Comment: I think that this would be really useful to have in the linked dupe target as well.

Answer (score 0):

The literal `@` in your password needs to be [URI encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).